# Unable to mute alarm sound in marshmallow android programatically

Tags: android, alarm, android-audiomanager, mute

i am trying to mute alarm in my custom android app.For Nuggets(Android N) i am using following code :

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        if (notificationManager != null && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
            try {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS), 0);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

and its working fine.and mutes the whole sounds even alarm. but its not working on Marshmallow.it gives me exception that class not found everytime after startActivityforResult().

```
 Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings$ZenAccessSettingsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.settings.Settings$ZenAccessSettingsActivity"
```

Now i am using following code which mutes all sounds in Marshmallow but Alarm still Rings on time with full sound.can anyone tell me where is the mistake in my code? or am i using wrong ways to do this?

```
 AudioManager mAlramMAnager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        if (mAlramMAnager != null) {

            mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
            mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
            mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
            mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);
            mAlramMAnager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);

        }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same exact problem